# How to access Elements in another Form or class

Tags: c#, forms, class

I want a program, which creates a List of Recipes, so something like a management system for Recipes. But I dont know how to access e.g. the List in the other class.

I set every freaking thing public.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //default constructor 

    public static List<Recipe> RecipeList = new List<Recipe>();
}

public partial class Form2
{
    //default constructor 

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, Eventargs e)
    {
        RecipeList.Add("Chili con Carne");
    }
}

public class Recipe
{
    //some properties and methods... 
    {
```

I cannot access the RecipeList there. How can I reach my goal to get the input for that Recipe in Form2 but then store a List globally where I can e.g. display the List of Recipes anywhere...

Comment: You can set static for RecipeList such as public static List<Recipe> RecipeList = new List<Recipe>();

Comment: i forgot that to write. It is already static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can do like this

```
public static  List<Recipe> RecipeList = new List<Recipe>();
Form1.RecipeList.Add("Chili con Carne");
```

Comment: do i always have to add Form1. infront of recipelist?

Comment: @LionHunter Yes, because your `RecipeList` is declare in `Form1`

Answer (score 1):

As your variable `public static List<Recipe> RecipeList` is static. You can use that variable by using the class name (`Form1`).

Here is what you can do:

```
public partial class Form2
{
    //default constructor 

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, Eventargs e)
    {
        Form1.RecipeList.Add("Chili con Carne");
    }
}
```